# Coupling patter for a methyl-butyl ether

Tags: organic-chemistry, nmr-spectroscopy, covalent-compounds

What would the high resolution H-NMR spectroscopy coupling pattern look like for the hydrogen attached to the carbon the arrow is pointing at? I am confused because there is a CH2 connected to either side of the carbon, but the hydrogens on each carbon are in different chemical environments since the one on the left is next to the oxygen in the ketone, so would it coupling pattern be a doublet of doublets? or just a doublet?

[image]